# Supporting of syntax highlighting of .env

Tags: webstorm

I am using WebStorm 2021.3.1.

There is a question on `.env` file, since it seems like it's not supporting the syntax highlighting, commenting etc. for `.env`, but it supports `.env.*` like `.env.example`.

How do I get `.env` supported? Below are screenshots for `.env` and `.env.local`

Below is screenshot for `.env`
[image]

Below is screenshot for `.env.local`
[image]

Comment: Please provide a screenshots for BOTH cases: where it works and where it does not. I want to see: 1) the file opened in the editor that would also show the editor tab (I want to see what file icon it uses + how the file gets highlighted) 2) find such a file in the Project View panel and invoke `View | Quick Documentation` on it (typically will be `Ctrl+Q` on Windows/Linux) -- show the popup content; need to see file type the IDE is using for it. So it should be 4 screenshots in total.

Comment: @LazyOne attached the information you requested

Comment: Go to `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`, locate `Text` file type there. You should have `.env` entry there. If you do -- remove it and add it to the `.env file` file type where it should be in the first place.

Comment: @LazyOne I could not find `.env file` file type..

Comment: @Arst You need to install a plugin for env files support. get one. it's called ".​env files support"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`, locate `Text` file type there. Based on your first screenshot you *should* have `.env` entry there.

- If you have it: remove it and re-add it to the `.env file` file type where it should be in the first place.
- If there is no such entry under `Text`, add `.env` pattern directly to the `.env file` file type. If such  pattern is already assigned to some another file type then the IDE will give you a prompt asking to remove it from another file type.

How `.env file` file type should look by default:

[image]